# Python can't import Whisper - ctypes.util.find_library('c') returns None

Tags: python, ctypes, openai-whisper

I use PyCharm on Windows 10 and run "Python 3.9.9". It's my code. I want to import whisper but get error in whisper.py line 70. I have checked that line: `libc_name = ctypes.util.find_library('c')`. `find_library` function can't find `'c'` library and returns `None`. How can I find libc and give absolute path or directory to `find_library` function?

main.py

```
import whisper

if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = whisper.load_model("base")
    result = model.transcribe("turkce.mp3")
    print(result["text"])
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.9.exe D:\PycharmProjects\SpeechToText\main.py 
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\SpeechToText\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import whisper as wp
  File "C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\whisper.py", line 70, in <module>
    libc = ctypes.CDLL(libc_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    if '/' in name or '\\' in name:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have tried uninstall whisper and reinstall from github;

```
pip uninstall whisper
pip install git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git
```

https://github.com/openai/whisper/discussions/120

Comment: This file ( https://github.com/graphite-project/whisper/blob/master/whisper.py ) belongs to the wrong "whisper". The uninstall may have failed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right i checked it again. I download source code from github ( github.com/openai/whisper ) then import my code like that "import whispermain.whisper as whisper" but it gives different  error 
```
"  File "C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\whispermain\whisper\audio.py", line 46, in load_audio
    except ffmpeg.Error as e:
AttributeError: module 'ffmpeg' has no attribute 'Error'"
```
Trying to solve that thank you.

Comment: I realized that I made same mistake while importing ffmpeg as I did whisper library. Reimported ffmpeg library from github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python then all work fine. Thank you again @MichaelButscher

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this exact problem by running a new environment in anaconda and reinstalling modules as an original environment did not accept the modules. As it is only my second day in coding, I am not sure what really helped but the original environment still does not work. I hope it helps.